# python sklearn model.predict getting same result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a 1095*2 train sample where the first column is corresponding to x and second column is y (y has 1095 different values). And I also have a 365*1 test sample.
I work on sklearn and try several models using model.fit(x,y), then model.predict(test), but what I am getting is merely a same number for 365 times.
However, the only model that works out (the result is not the same) is Naive-Bayes GaussionNB(). 
Can anyone explain to me why that is happening?

Comment: I think i found the problem. My x was too small, mostly just 0.01-0.1, so I multiply each x by 1000 to enlarge them.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use the `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` in that case.